# Object functions not showing up with console.log

Tags: javascript, object, logging, console, ace-editor

OK, I'm trying to show all functions/properties of an object (specifically of an [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about&api=selection) `editor` object), using `console.log(editor)` (or `console.log(editor.getSession())` for that matter) via Chrome's JavaScript Console.

The thing is - having studied the very code behind Ace - I know there are functions (and I have used them) - which are **not** showing up when I'm trying to "print" the object.

What's going on? How can I get the full object/function tree? (preferably in some readable format)

---

**HINT:**

I actually need this in order to get a complete list of available methods (most of which is not even documented).

---

**EDIT :**

Steps to reproduce the issue :

- Go to http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about&api=selection
- Open JavaScript console
- Inspect `editor.getSession()`
- E.g. `editor.getSession().getBreakpoints()` is *not* listed
- However, if you try using it, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some frameworks override the console.log functionality.

Instead of `console.log(editor)` you can write `editor.valueOf()` in most cases to get all attributes and methods.

there is also an enhanced way:

```
for (key in editor) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(editor[key]);
    // or
    editor[key].valueOf();
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but unfortunately it's not working. Please check the edit to my initial post.

Comment: it might be possible that these getters and setters are generated during access. So they do not exist in reality. if you look into console.log you will see 'session' which is responsible for getSession as well as the property 'breakpoints'. and the methods are available in the _proto_ section.

Comment: and as i wrote: `for (key in editor) {console.log(key);}`also shows up getSession in a list!

Comment: OK. Yep, that's it! (I'm not that experienced with JS, and to be honest I had no clue what that `__proto__` section could be hiding). Thanks a lot! You can't imagine how much time you've saved me. Ace Editor is great, but it's still like 90% undocumented. So the only way I could discover any meaningful function was to go through its 14000+ lines of code (actually guessing). So, that's great!

Comment: OK, one last question (just in case you know) : is there any easy way (apart from the function names) to also get the arguments it takes (I mean according to its definition) - like `this.setBreakpoints = function(rows)` or like `setBreakpoints(rows)`?

Comment: when you enter the function (e.g. editor.getSession) without '()' it will show you the implementation and its parameters.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! (I suppose I have to brush my JS skills up a bit... lol)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i in ace){ console.log(i); };
```

Or try

```
inspect(ace);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one is not working either. Please check the edit to my initial post.